# how to set dropdown to select after onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown with few options in it and a onclick event on a button , after making the selection from the dropdown and clicking on the button how do i set the dropdown to its default that is select by JavaScript.

```
 <select id="userType">
              <option value="Select" disabled selected 
              id="myDefault">Select</option>
              <option value="1">Games</option>
              <option value="2">Movies</option>
           </select>
 <button type="button" name="button"onclick="addOption()">Send</button>

function addOption(){
 if (userType.value === "Select") {
    alert("Please select correct option");
 }
 else{
    console.log(userType.options[userType.selectedIndex].value);
 }
 document.getElementById('userType').value = "Select";
```

}

Comment: you mean you want to reset to default when you click on button?

Comment: yes, the values of the selected option gets passed on and the dropdown sets to "Select"

Comment: so you want the drop down to reset after clicking the button. i mean it should reset to the default value in the drop down ?

Comment: @Jok3r yes!!!!!

Comment: you can use "$('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);" to reset you selectbox value.

Comment: @tankit88 Requirement at original Question is described as _"after making the selection from the dropdown and clicking on the button"_, note "after" portion of requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>

<body>


<form id="myForm">
  
<select id="a">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  
</select>
<br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset">
</form>



</body>
</html>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('a').selectedIndex = 0;

}
</script>
```

try this

Comment: the reset() is to be done on the form ? can't it be done on the select tag??

Comment: try it i have changed.

Comment: dude thanks a lot it worked , turns out there was some issue with materialize css framework that was not allowing it to update it by default that i have to check otherwise its working fine ....thanks again!!!!

Comment: thanks for your feedback and please vote for my answer if it useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straight forward. Just select the input by id and set its value to whatever the default should be.

```js
function addOption(){
  // Do stuff...and then:
  document.getElementById('userType').value = "Select";

}
```

```html
<select id="userType">
              <option value="Select" disabled selected 
              id="myDefault">Select</option>
              <option value="1">Games</option>
              <option value="2">Movies</option>
           </select>
 <button type="button" name="button"onclick="addOption()">Send</button>
```

Comment: i have tried that but after clicking on the button it's showing the previously selected value.

Comment: My script is working in the above snippet. Perhaps updating your question with the JS script you're using can help us elude to why yours is not.

Comment: I have added my script , it's quite simple after the condition it should trigger the event and the set the dropdown to default , although in the console it is showing Select but not updating in the page itself.

Comment: Beg your pardon for not getting back sooner. I'm glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your working code:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="userType">
              <option value="Select" disabled selected 
              id="myDefault">Select</option>
              <option value="1">Games</option>
              <option value="2">Movies</option>
           </select>
 <button type="button" name="button">Send</button>
```

Comment: Forgot to include JQuery in your snippet :)

Comment: yep, i am so sorry. thanks for remind me. i just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `change` event to `<select>` element, declare a variable, at event handler set variable to `true` to verify that `change` event has occurred. At `click` of `<button>` set `select` `.selectedIndex` property to `0` if `Boolean` value is `true`, set `Boolean` to `false`.

```html
<script>
  var changed, select;
  function addOption() {
    if (changed) {
      select.selectedIndex = 0;
      changed = false;
    }
  }
  onload = function() {
    select = document.getElementById("userType");
    select.onchange = function() {
      changed = true;
    }

  }
</script>

<select id="userType">
              <option value="Select" disabled selected 
              id="myDefault">Select</option>
              <option value="1">Games</option>
              <option value="2">Movies</option>
           </select>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="addOption()">Send</button>
```